# Android-Cast : androidx MediaRouteButton No muestra la lista de dispositivos conectados

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-play-services

estoy realizando un experimento desarrollando una aplicación para compartir con Google Cast un vídeo en Streaming. La idea es que en la pantalla del reproductor sale un botón y puedes compartir con los servicios de Google Cast.

El Layout es el siguiente:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".playerM">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
    class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
    android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

y la clase seria así :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_m);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    try {
        mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
        mSessionManager = mCastContext.getSessionManager();

        MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getString(R.string.app_id))).build();
        mMediaRouteButton =(MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
        mMediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, mMediaRouteButton);
        Log.e("","Exception CastButtonFactory. : " + this + mMediaRouteButton);

    }catch (Exception e){

        Log.e("","Exception cast : "+e);
    }

    try{
        videoMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_TV_SHOW);
        videoMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Total Player");
        videoMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("","Exception videomNetadata : "+e);
    }

    video = findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    withland = video.getWidth();
    video.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), mMediaRouteButton);
        }
    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    uri = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    //mediaPlayer(uri,video);

}
```

He añadido al Manifest Metadata:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="luis.dominguez.totalplayerexample.CastOptionsProvider" />
```

Y también he añadido el código ID de la aplicación que he sacado de aquí https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview. Esta siguiendo la guía de https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/chromecast-android.

He mirado en los Logs y no sale ningún error, el símbolo del botón aparece pero al pulsarlo no pasa nada y en los Log no sale noticia de alguna de la interacción. La cuestión es que la ejecución no da error alguno y ya no se me ocurre que puede estar pasando.

He probado con las id de prueba y tampoco. Puede ser porque se reproduce un vídeo .m3u8 o alguien sabe si al reproducir con un VideoView se bloquea cualquier interacción ??

Answer (score 1):

intenta llamarlo con

```
mMediaRouteButton.performClick();
```

Esto suele ocurrir porque tu app no está registrada correctamente (lo cuál debería revisar) y por ende no puede lanzar los dispositivos disponibles de casteo compatibles con Google Cast.

Verifica también que estés estableciendo el contexto de google cast desde un activity ya que en fragment no funciona según la documentacion de Cast Google Developers

Fuente:
https://developers.google.com/cast/

Comment: Gracias Uriel, sabes si por casualidad hay códigos de prueba ? ya me paso algo parecido con admob que no me salían los anuncios (por un problema con el enlace a la aplicación) pero sí me salían los de prueba. He probado con algunos códigos que dicen que son de prueba en otros foros pero no funcionaba ninguno.

Comment: ya probaste con poner el código de tu aplicación?..
Cuando registras la aplicación, te dan un código para que tu app pueda leerla

Comment: De hecho ese código es de prueba

Comment: Si, lo he probado. El problema es que cuando realiza esta tarea lo que parece es que la ui se queda bloqueada. No sale un error en los logs, pero al realizar él performClick() me ha salido que el thread principal esta realizando demasiado trabajo. Quiero probar a poner el botón como parte de los controles de media player, igual así si que aparece. Gracias por la respuesta, voy a realizar mas pruebas con esa función.

Comment: Que reproductor de vídeo usas?...
ExoPlayer, nativo?....

Comment: el nativo con mediaplayer, pero lo voy a probar con exoplayer